# DDD - No Lazy loading - how to do certain tasks without draining the database?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm working on a module for a larger solution.
In this solution they tried in the past to work with DDD.
However that didn't turn out how it should of been because there was no DDD expert. (and there still isn't one present imo.)
Everything was under a single root aggregate, lazy loading was enabled, and so on.

Now for the new module we want to make it better.
However i'm failing to see how i can use DDD without lazy loading and not drain the entire database.

For example i have an object let's call it "B".

B has a flag let's say "AwesomeFlag"

B has children

If one of B's children is Awesome, then B is awesome as well.

If none of B's children is Awesome, then B isn't awesome.

Now if I would not work with DDD; I'd just get B and execute a linq query that check's if one of B's children is awesome without actually retrieving all of the children.

However if i got a domainobject where i am not allowed to perform queries, how can i do this?

Is DDD forcing me to get all of B's children just to get the calculated flag "IsAwesome" to work?

Or how am i supposed to do this correctly in a DDD environment?

A small hint in which direction i need to focus my research on would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As I was a bit broad in what my question is I'd like to rephrase whilst still using the same terms to be consistent.

B is awesome when one of it's children is awesome.

B itself, does not have a flag "awesome" as this is a calculated field based on the children.

B could have quite a few children, with the children each having allot of properties and data, which you do not want to retrieve just to check if one of the children is Awesome.

B has a method ShouldIBecomeADeveloper
If one of B's children is awesome, making B awesome, it should return a boolean "true"

If none of B's children are awesome, making B not awesome, it should return a boolean "false"

Comment: The idea behind "no lazy loading" recommendation is to make people think more about their design and keep the aggregate as small as possible. But I am afraid anyone can answer your question with such a trivial example. People have to get some basic idea about your domain to answer any DDD question, so add more info to your question and also read [this](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838)

Comment: @wolverine thank you for your reply.
I've recently read the article you sent me and I've watched all the Pluralsight courses on the subject. I even read the book that Eric Evans had written.
But it's all too abstract or focusses on examples where performance is not regarded. Or they solve it using lazy loading.
I'd like to see a real world example where they have an aggregate root containing an enourmous list of children.
Where they validate/update without retrieving the entire List of objects.
Where they can check a flag like my example without retrieving the entire object collection.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: although this is somehow a valid question, it is very broad, thus it may have many different valid answers.*

You need to analyze the business requirements regarding the valid states in which the system is allowed to be. For this you need to answer the question: after a child of `B` becomes `awesome`, *how fast* needs `B` to become `awesome` as well?

There are two answers:

1. Immediately, in a strongly consistent matter. This means that the "awesome mutation" of a child of B and the "awesome mutation" of B are performed in an atomic fashion, they are in the same transaction. In this case you must load B and all its children before mutating one of its children awesomeness. The children of B are nested entities inside the B Aggregate.
2. It can be delayed, *eventually* changing its awesomeness to match the business rule, that is, the system can be for some time in a temporary invalid state. In this case, the children of B are also Aggregates. You need a way of mutating B when one of its "past childrens" mutate and for this you can use a Saga/Process manager.

In neither of the two cases you don't use lazy-loading, there is not such thing in case of DDD Aggregates. You can't anyway, if you have pure Aggregates, with no dependencies to Repositories (as you should).

Comment: Hey @Constantin, you know your stuff, thank you for your reply.
I've updated the question to be more precise and less broad.
If you find the time, could you give me your opinion on how you'd solve it in a DDD environment? Keeping performance in mind.
Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @NickV so I understand that you need strong consistency, right?

Comment: that is right. In our real world app we're making a financial application so delay is out of the question for our domain experts.

Comment: @NickV I know that financial applications are *special*, but you need to think if you really want that strong consistency and I'm referring to this particular case. Do you really need a B to be able to become a Developer a picosecond after one of its children becomes awesome? And also, what happens if he becomes a Developer and then all of its children step down from being awesome? (I know that you have anonymized the use-case :) ) You may need this if the events are somehow temporarily or causally coupled.

Answer (score 1):

> B itself, does not have a flag "awesome" as this is a calculated field based on the children.

Even though "awesome" is a calculated field any operation you perform on the child entity has to go through "B" only, as it is the aggregate root. So you could have a state in "B" called `numberOfAwesomeChildren` and a child can become awesome/not awesome only when some operation happens on it and since all the operations are directed via "B" only, you can update the `numberOfAwesomeChildren` whenever a child becomes awesome/not awesome.

So "B" is awesome when `numberOfAwesomeChildren` is greater than zero.

Even this solution won't solve your lazy loading problem, since to perform an operation on a child entity you will end up loading all the child entity. You may have to  have a re-look at your design.

Comment: thank you for the feedback.
What i'm getting out of this; is that it is quite impossible to do this without some form of lazy loading. The better answer you give would be to then relook at the design of our aggregates and figure out a new one.
I'm just having trouble seeing the benefit after a while.
Without DDD its as simple as dbContext.Children.Any(c => c.BId == requestedB.Id && c.IsAwesome)
With DDD it's a heap of trouble.

Comment: And this is a simple use case, not asking for any big thing here. So for now Im failing to see how DDD can be performing well in real life.
DDD is great from a functional perspective, but looking at performance its quite iffy.
I know there must be a way to do it. DDD has existed for years so it must work. But there is no DDD Expert at this project where i can ask simple things like this. 
So i'm going to propose to drop it or ask for a DDD expert on premise.
Because if we stick with this descision whilst not even fully knowing the answer to a simple question like this we're doomed to fail.